# My navigation bar is different with Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, uinavigationbar, opera

[On Chrome and Opera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPRL5.png)

[On Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igIUz.png)

I didn't find the exact answer/solution for my case :

**I am a rookie in this stuff, but I try hard not to be**

I heard about css reset so it can be the same on every web browser but that didn't work (or I did it wrong, but I looked a video on the internet about how to do it)

There might be a command that Firefox doesn't understand in my css sheet, so I might need to "translate" in a command it understands

(just like the `-webkit-border-top-left-radius` that didn't work on Firefox, so I had to added `moz-border-radius-topleft`)

***Can somebody give me at least a clue ? So I could know what I'm looking for to fix this problem***

***Thank you in advance for your answer***

```css
body.accueil {
 overflow-y:hidden;
    width:100%;
 background-image:url(imagedef.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
 
 
 
}
body.quizz {
 overflow-x: hidden;
    width:100%;
 background-image:url(quiresu.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
 
 
 
}
body.objectif{
 overflow-x: hidden;
 margin: 0;
    width:100%;
  background-image:url(imagedefre.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
 overflow: hidden;
}
body.realisation{
 overflow-x: hidden;
 margin: 0;
    width:100%;
 background-color: #A0A09F;
 overflow: hidden;
}
body.liste {
 overflow-x: hidden;
 margin: 0;
    width:100%;
 background-color: #333333;
 overflow: auto;
}
body {
 overflow-x: hidden;
 margin: 0;
    width:100%;
 overflow: hidden;
 
}
body {
 overflow-x: hidden;
 margin: 0;
    width:100%;
 overflow: hidden;
 
}
/*#site {
 width: 1000px;
 margin: auto;
 background-color: white;
}*/



#menu img {
 float: left;
 list-style-type: none;
 position: relative;
 left: 5%;
    margin:auto;
 margin-top: 1%
 
 
}
#menu {
 min-width: 100px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 15%;
 position: left;
 background-color: white;
    margin:auto;
 

}

#menu ul {
 float: left;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: 5%;
 padding-bottom:1%
}   

#menu ul li {
 float: left;
 list-style-type: none;
 position: relative;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: auto;
    display: inline;
 height: 100%;
 
 
}
 
 

#menu ul li a{
 text-align: center;
 
 padding-top: 10%;
 background:linear-gradient(#EAF9F7,#EAF9F7,#EAF9F7,#EAF9F7,#EAF9F7,#EAF9F7,#DEE6E5,#DEE6E5,#D2DBDA);
 height: 30%;
 width: 250px;
 color: black;
 text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
 margin-top: 10%;
 margin-left: 20%;
 box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;
 font-size :0.9vw;
 
 
}

#menu ul li a:hover{
 color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    background:linear-gradient(#A3ABAA,#788280,#5A605F,#363B3A,#283533,#363B3A,#363B3A,#363B3A,#363B3A);
 
 
}
#menu ul li a.current{
     color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    background:linear-gradient(#A3ABAA,#788280,#5A605F,#363B3A,#283533,#363B3A,#363B3A,#363B3A,#363B3A);
 
}


#menu li:first-child, 
#menu li:first-child a {
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 10px;
 
}

#menu li:last-child, 
#menu li:last-child a {
 -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 10px;
 
}


#banner2 {
 display: block;
 background-color: #424242;
 height: 3%;
 width: 100%;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
 
  
}

#banner3 {
 display: block;
 width: 50%;
 height:40%;
 background-color: white;
 margin-left:25%;
 margin-top: -15px; 
 

}
#banner3.liste3 {
 
 

}
#banner3.accueil3 {
 display: block;
 width: 50%;
 height:100%;
 background-color: white;
    text-align: center; 
 margin-bottom:-2%;
 
 
}

#banner3.objectif3 {
 display: block;
 width: 50%;
 height:40%;
 background-color: white;
    text-align: center; 
 
}
.objetext {
margin-left: 30px;


}


#banner4.objectif4 {
 display: block;
 width: 50%;
 height:40%;
 background-color: white;
 margin-left:25%;
 text-align: auto;
 
}

#banner4 {
 display: block;
 width: 50%;
 height:426px;
 background-color: white;
 margin-left:450px;
 margin-top: -31px;
 text-align: auto;
 
}
div.gallery {
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    float: left;
    width: 180px;
}

div.gallery:hover {
    border: 1px solid #777;
}

div.gallery img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

div.desc {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
 background-color:white;
}

.picorange{

 float: left;
 margin: 0 0 20px 20px;
 
}
.titre2{
 margin-left: 40px;
 text-align: center;
 
}
.titre3{
 margin-left: 63px;
 
 
}
#footer {
 text-align: center;
 display: block;
 background-color: #424242;
 height: 6%;
 padding-bottom:-2%;
 
}

#footer p {
 color: white;
 font-weight: bold;
 position: relative;
 top: 18px;
 font-size :1.1vw;
 
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>ACCUEIL</title>
     <meta name="viewport" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="style/loggo.png" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css"  />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-width: 1650px)" href="style/media1.css"  />
     
 </head>
 <body class= accueil>
 
 
  <div id="site">
   
   <div id="menu">
    <img id="logo" alt="JARAMANN CAR" src="style/logo.png" width = "13%">
    <ul>
     <li><a class="current" href="index.html">ACCUEIL</a></li>
     <li><a  href="REALISATION.html">REALISATION DU SITE</a></li>
     <li><a  href="OBJECTIF.html">OBJECTIF DU SITE</a></li>
     <li><a  href="LISTE.html">LISTE DE VOITURE</a></li>
     <li><a  href="QUESTIONNAIRE.html">QUESTIONNAIRE</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <div id="banner2">
   </div>

   <div id="banner3" class= "accueil3">
    <img class="imageac" src="style/german_cars.png" width =" 100%" />
    <p>
    <font color=#333333 face="helvetica" size="+4">
    Choisissez parmi plus de 35 modèle de voiture allemandes.
    <br /></font>
    </p>

    <p>
    <font face="helvetica" size="+1.5">Choisissez et Personnalisez jusqu'à 35 voitures de marque allemande allant de SUV à voiture de sport.
    <br />Toutes marques proposées sont de provenances allemandes.<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /></font>
               <a href="QUESTIONNAIRE.html"> <img border="0" alt="QUESTIONNAIRE" src="style/orange.JPG" width="30%" class="picorange">
      </a>
      <font color=black face="monospace" size="+3" class="titre2">
    Vous ne savez pas quelle type de voiture vous convient?
      <br /><br /></font>
      <font color=black face="monospace" size="+2" class="titre3">
    Remplissez un questionnaire<br /> &#160 &#160 &#160 &#160qui déterminera pour vous <br />&#160 &#160 &#160 &#160votre type de voiture.
      <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /></font>
                
      </p>
     

   </div>

   
   <div id="footer">
    <p>Jaramann | Tous droits réservés</p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```